# Where is the KODI folder in Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: kodi

Installed Ubuntu 22.10 and KODI with no problems. In Ubuntu 22.04 and earlier versions KODI is a Hidden folder in the Home directory.That doesn't seem to be the case for U-22.10.  I was able to find a kodi4 folder under the user folder but the layout is not quite the same as the previous versions folders.
Normally I do not use flatpack or snap to install programs.(personal preference) May have used flatpac in his case.  Found KODI folder exactly where Tes said it would be. Thanks.

Comment: Depends upon the method you used to install kodi. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1448520/edit) to include that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found mine. I will bet you used flatpak install?

The folder should be in home/USERNAME/.var/app/tv.kodi.kodi

Tes

Comment: Tes, Thanks for the answer. Found the folder exactly where you said it would be.

Comment: Glad I could help! I'm a total n00b myself with the whole linux thing but I'm learnin! lol